# R: Centering a map in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I would like to center the outline of Jersey in the middle of the bounding box (See attached image below)

[image]

This is what the shapefile looks like before using the `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(200000.732,905000.646), ylim=c(-5812.321,900000.543))`

[image]

Code is as follows:

```
graph1<-ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=middlestates,colour="black",fill="#D3D3D3",aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_polygon(data=df,colour="black",aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=ALG))+
  ggtitle("Figure 2.2A: Assessment Results for\nGeneral Aquatic Life Use, Spatial Extent")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(200000.732,905000.646), ylim=c(-5812.321,900000.543))+
  ggsn::scalebar(df,location="bottomleft",dist = 50,st.dist=0.02,st.size=3, height=0.01)+
  scale_fill_manual("Aquatic Life Designated\nUse 2014 Assessment",values=c((values=c(colors))))+
  cowplot::background_grid(major= "none",minor = "none") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0.8,0.2),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size=12),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12, face="bold"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold",hjust=0.5))

pdf(file="Figure 2.2A.pdf",width=13,height=12,paper="a4")
north2(graph1, x = 0.10, y = 0.89, scale = 0.1, symbol = 3)
dev.off()
```

Is there anyway to do this without changing the

```
coord_cartesian(xlim=c(200000.732,905000.646), ylim=c(-5812.321,900000.543))
```

line??
I would like to keep the way the map looks.
Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can probably do this by taking the bounding box of the shapefile, taking a small buffer around that, and then setting limits from that. Including your data would help with debugging.

Comment: Not sure how I would do that.. I'm new to using R @camille

Comment: That's fine, can you explain more what's going on then? Are you subsetting from a larger shapefile? If so, what states are in it? What type of object is `middlestates`? Where did the coordinates that are in `coord_cartesian` come from? This would all be good info to include in your question

Comment: No I'm not subsetting from a larger shapefile. Middlestates is a LargeSpatialPolygonDataFrame. The coordinates that are in coord_cartesian I got from a script from a coworker of fine. Sorry I'm still getting used to formatting my question the correct way.

Comment: Okay then, can you update your question explaining more of what's in the shapefile, such as what states? What does the plot look like when you don't set the coordinate limits?

Comment: @Camille see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mockup of similar shapefiles. I'm using `sf`, because it's great for quickly filtering or analyzing spatial data, works like `dplyr` but for shapes, and because it plots easily with the newest version of `ggplot2` (might need to use the github version). If your shapefiles are in Spatial* formats, you can use `st_as_sf` to create an `sf` object.

To get an `sf` of states and an `sf` of New Jersey towns, I used functions from `tigris` that download shapefiles from the Census. That was just the easiest way I had to get the shapefiles; you use whatever ones you're already working with.

I filtered the `mid_sf` object, which is an `sf` of the states in the region, for just New Jersey, then piped it into `st_buffer` to place a small buffer around it, then `st_bbox` to get its bounding box.

There are two plots: one without the coordinate limits set, and one with them set based on `nj_bbox`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

us_sf <- tigris::states(class = "sf", cb = T)

mid_sf <- us_sf %>%
    filter(NAME %in% c("New York", "New Jersey", "Pennsylvania", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Rhode Island", "Massachusetts", "Maryland", "Virginia", "West Virginia"))

nj_towns_sf <- tigris::county_subdivisions(state = "NJ", class = "sf", cb = T)

# dist is in degrees latitude & longitude
nj_bbox <- mid_sf %>%
    filter(NAME == "New Jersey") %>%
    st_buffer(dist = 0.15) %>%
    st_bbox()
#> Warning in st_buffer.sfc(st_geometry(x), dist, nQuadSegs): st_buffer does
#> not correctly buffer longitude/latitude data

nj_bbox
#>      xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
#> -75.70961  38.77852 -73.74398  41.50742

nj_map <- ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = mid_sf, color = "gray40", fill = "white", size = 0.5) +
    geom_sf(data = nj_towns_sf, color = "gray20", fill = "tomato", alpha = 0.7, size = 0.25)

nj_map
```

[image]

```r
nj_map +
    coord_sf(ndiscr = 0, xlim = c(nj_bbox$xmin, nj_bbox$xmax), ylim = c(nj_bbox$ymin, nj_bbox$ymax))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and for your patience! @Camille

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)


states <- map_data("state")
dim(states)
#> [1] 15537     6

head(states)

nj_df <- subset(states, region == "new jersey")
head(nj_df)

counties <- map_data("county")
nj_county <- subset(counties, region == "new jersey")
head(nj_county)


nj_base <- ggplot(data = nj_df, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) + 
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray")
nj_base + theme_nothing()


bj_base + theme_nothing() + 
  geom_polygon(data = nj_county, fill = NA, color = "white") +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)  # get the state border back on top
```